# How to use displayed text from a search input to display data from a previous search in Javascript using localStorage

Tags: javascript

I am creating a weather app where a search history is generated by the user and can be used to display data from previous searches.

The section in the HTML it is being displayed to is:

```
<div id="search-history" class="list-group">
 <!-- DISPLAY SEARCHED ITEMS -->
</div>
```

And the JS is:

```
//------------------ SEARCH CITY AND STORE SEARCH ----------------------
var searchCity = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var cityName = cityInputEl.value.trim();
    if (cityName) {
        getCityWeather(cityName);
        cityInputEl.value = "";
        var searchedCity = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("CityList")) || [cityName];
        var storedCities = {city: cityName};
        searchedCity.push(storedCities);

        localStorage.setItem("CityList", JSON.stringify(searchedCity));
    } else {
        alert("Enter a city name");
    }
    createCityList(searchedCity);
}
```

The getCityWeather function that is being called just returns the weather it that has been fetched from an API. The real problem is here where I'm trying to create buttons which can be used to display the name of the last city and when you click on it, the weather info is displayed once again for whichever city was previously searched.

```
//Create search history list
function createCityList() {
    var searchedCities = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("CityList")) || [];
    searchHistory.innerHTML="";
     for (i = 0; i<searchedCities.length; i++){
        var buttonEl = document.createElement("button");
        buttonEl.classList = "list-group-item list-group-item-action";
        buttonEl.id = "searchedCity" + i;
        buttonEl.textContent = searchedCities[i].city;
        searchHistory.appendChild(buttonEl);
    }
}


// Search old city
function searchPreviousCity(searchedCities) {
    var buttonElArr = [];
    for (i = 0; i<searchedCities.length; i++) {
        buttonElArr[i] = document.getElementById("searchedCity" + i);
        console.log("BUTTON ARR", buttonElArr)
    }
    
    buttonElArr.map((oldSearch) => {
        oldSearch.addEventListener("click", function() {
            getCityWeather(oldSearch.innerHTML);
        })
    });
}


//clear scearch history
clearSearchHistory.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    localStorage.clear(event);
    searchHistory.textContent = "";
});

createCityList();

cityFormEl.addEventListener("submit", searchCity);
```

Basically I've been messing around with it trying to store the searches in an array and just have the list of buttons display the weather info of the respective city.

If Button1: CityA, Button2: CityB, Button3: CityC.. When I click Button2, the weather of city B should show.

Answer (score 0):

you should try create a new table in database and save the userid,search,timestamp and fetch the data when ever you need

Comment: I messed up the question.. I meant to say that it's in local storage and not a server.

Comment: you can use cookie because you have to store previous data then only you can achieve your desire result